# Pygame Collision Detection: AttributeError

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I've been banging my head against this for a while. I am trying to make a game with PyGame and I got up to the collision segment and have been stuck for a while and have checked a few threads.

This is the code I have (removed other methods and conditional statements in between, but left the relevant parts). I am a little confused by the error because I do a self.imageRect = self.image.get_rect() in both classes init, yet I have this error. The error was specifically:
"**AttributeError:** 'Pebble' object has no attribute 'rect'" when the program attempts to carry out the collision detection part in the dog class. What have I been doing wrong?

```
import random
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock() # fps clock

screenSize = WIDTH, HEIGHT = [800, 600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screenSize)

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
bgColorRGB = [153, 204, 255]
background.fill(bgColorRGB)


pebbleGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
pebbleSingle = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle() 
dogSingle = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Dog(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, path, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #call Sprite initializer
        self.image = pygame.image.load(path) # load sprite from path/file loc.
        self.imageRect = self.image.get_rect() # get bounds of image
        self.imageWidth = self.image.get_width()
        self.imageHeight = self.image.get_height()
        self.speed = speed

    # sets location of the image, gets the start location of object
    # sets the start location as the image's left and top location
    def setLocation(self, location):
        self.imageRect.left, self.imageRect.top = location


    def checkCollision(self, pebble, dogGroup):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(pebble, dogGroup, False):
                print "collided"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
class Pebble(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, path, speed, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        self.image = pygame.image.load(path) 
        self.imageRect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.imageWidth = self.image.get_width()
        self.imageHeight = self.image.get_height()
        self.imageRect.left, self.imageRect.top = location
        self.speed = speed # initialize speed
        self.isDragged = False


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def startGame():

    pebblePaths = ['images/pebble/pebble1.jpg', 'images/pebble/pebble2.jpg']
    for i in range(3):
        pebblePath = pebblePaths[random.randrange(0, len(pebblePaths))]
        pebbleSpeed = [random.randrange(1, 7), 0]
        pebbleLocation = [0, random.randrange(20, HEIGHT - 75)]
        pebble = Pebble(pebblePath, pebbleSpeed, pebbleLocation)
        pebbleGroup.add(pebble)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


        for pebble in pebbleGroup:
            dog.checkCollision(pebble, dogSingle)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30) # wait a little before starting again
startGame()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expecting `Sprite.rect`, so change from

```
self.imageRect = self.image.get_rect()
#to
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Note

```
self.imageWidth = self.image.get_width()
self.imageHeight = self.image.get_height()
self.imageRect.left, self.imageRect.top = location
```

These are not necessary, since rect's have many properties, like `self.rect.width` or `self.rect.topleft = location` . Another useful one is `centerx`.

full list at: [pygame Rect docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)